# Firebase security rules doesnot work for another path

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```html
private void showingDatafromDatabase() {


        if (currentUser != null) {

            String uid = currentUser.getUid();

            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

            ref.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    UserInfo info = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInfo.class);

                    assert info != null;

                    String coin = info.getCoins();
                    String isAvailable = info.getIsRefered();
                    TextView cointext = view.findViewById(R.id.coinstext);
                    cointext.setText(coin);

                    coinChecker = Integer.parseInt(coin);

                    boolean isRefer = Boolean.parseBoolean(isAvailable);
                    if (isRefer) {
                    } else {
                        inputrefer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    querydailyrewards();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    }


    private void querydailyrewards() {

        if (currentUser != null) {

            String uid = currentUser.getUid();
            DatabaseReference queryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Refer Code");

            Query query = queryRef.child(uid).orderByChild("isCheckin");
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                        UserInfo data = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInfo.class);

                        assert data != null;
                        showingDatafromDailyRewards();

                    } else {

                        addDailyRewardValue();

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }

    }
```

```html
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
projectname
|
|Refer Code|
|          |
|         uid
|            |- refercode
|            |- uid
|Users |
       |
     uid
       |- coins
       |- email
       |- name
       |- refercode
```

I am using firebase auth rule so only user can access there own content but it was working only for only one path and it show me permission denied error for other rule.This rule working fine for User query but it show me error on Premission denied on Refer Code Query.I onlu want user to access ther uid content not other content

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code of the query that's not working the way you expect.  Security rules by themselves are not useful unless they are paired with client code to be allowed or denied.  Also make sure that your code checks to see if the a user is signed in before making the query.

Comment: yes user is sign in app every path was taking uid .When i update database it show premission denied because Users rules as mention upper does give him to access uid for other query

Comment: ".read": "auth != null",
               ".write": "auth != null"                                                                                                                This rule working fine but only upper  rules not work

Comment: @DougStevenson i update my question.Please take a look

Comment: @DougStevenson take a look